# query for serial number

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers

Just want to get an idea & advise.. how to get the exact result for my situation when query..see below table..

[image]

I try to use this query and its look fine..but the problem is when I give the input `ABC1001Z` (different only last character `Z`).. the query still return `Honda` as result.. it's supposed not return any result/no result found.. any solution for my case?

```
SELECT Name 
FROM CarNo 
WHERE ('ABC1001Z' BETWEEN Start AND End)
AND (len('ABC1001Z') = len (Start));
```

Your kind support is much appreciated..

Comment: This result is totally expected, because `ABC1001Z` is lexicographically between `ABC1000A` and `ABC3000A`.  Tell us what you are trying to do here and maybe we can help.

Comment: Yes. Normalise your data. You have an alphabetical prefix, a 4 digit number, and an optional alphabetical suffix. Store the serial as a set of these 3 components

Comment: FYI, the database format currently as like that (from developer), i just want to get the exact result when query.. just give the result if the input only on that range (id 1 & 2).. besides from that..its should not return any output.. if i give the input last character as B,C,D,E....Z the result still take id = 2 (Honda).. maybe need to use another query to get the result that i want...pls advise..

Answer (score 0):

Update you code to

```
SELECT Name FROM CarNo 
WHERE (SUBSTRING('ABC1001Z',0,7) BETWEEN SUBSTRING(Start,0,7) AND  SUBSTRING(End,0,7) )
AND (len('ABC1001Z') = len (Start));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's what you are looking for:

```
SELECT Name FROM CarNo 
WHERE (Start = 'ABC1001Z' OR End = 'ABC1001Z')
      AND (len('ABC1001Z') = len(Start));
```

Comment: if using this code..i can't seacrh for id = 1..only function for id = 2

Comment: @twister I don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: i tried to use your code by input ABC1001 but dont give any result.. it should appear Toyota..

Comment: Why? For the same reason you get Honda in results, your logic condraticts itself. Please provide more information on your logic, more sample input and sample output.

Comment: ABC1001Z, ABC1001, ABC1001A actually variable value..can change based on input.. ABC1001Z = should not give any result...ABC1001 = Toyota.. ABC1001A = Honda

Comment: @twister **Why** should it give these results?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the "number" in the middle to be treated as a number.  This suggests something like this:

```
where left('ABC1001Z', 3) between left(start, 3) and left(end, 3) and
      substr('ABC1001Z', 4, 4) + 0 between substr(start, 4, 4) + 0 and substr(end, 4, 4) + 0
```

I'm not sure how the last character relates to a `between` query of this form, so I'm not addressing that.

Comment: tq..but the result still not resolved for my situation...it display all record that match with middle number